# Would being on paltalk 8 hours a day consume a lot of bandwidth?

Tags: internet-connection, bandwidth

My household bandwidth is over 60 GB per month, and my guess is that it is so high because someone listens to palk talk audio for over 8 hours per day.

Could palk talk really use this much bandwidth?

Is there a utility tool I could put on a computer to see how much it is consuming?

Answer (score 0):

Paltalk bandwidth heavily depends on the number of users per room, the number of those users on audio, the number of those users on video, and the number of users you are listening/watching.

There is no definitive answer to this question, as we have no idea what is going on in the room in question.

You can monitor your bandwidth using multiple tools, I prefer tools by AnalogX:  http://www.simplehelp.net/2007/09/09/how-to-monitor-your-internet-bandwidth-usage-in-windows/